# Sharepoint : Metadata Property Mappings question

Tags: sharepoint, search

I've made a Metadata Property Mappings and I'm trying to use the "default" search result  webpart to display the result of a search. The custom search form that I made use the parameter "k" (for keyword) in the query string, but the search use all the fields of my elements. I want to only search on a specific "metadata property mapping" that I made... Is there a parameter that I can add to the QueryString for that? Where can I look for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found it with that article :
http://blogs.tamtam.nl/appie/2009/03/31/BasicSearchMetadataPropertyMappings.aspx

You just have to add the name of the property with ":" and then your keywords. 
Here's an example :

?k=Author:"Keyword"  will search only in the author metadata.